# C# User Controls: access controls properties

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I have created a control and added a TextBox inside that control,
I am attaching that control to a .aspx page via

```
<%@ Register Src="../UserControls/AccountSearchControl.ascx" TagName="SearchControl"
TagPrefix="csr" %>
```

and

```
<csr:SearchControl ID="AccountSearchControlBox" runat="server"  OnSearchButtonClick="RetreiveAccounts" />
```

On .aspx.cs file I want to access the value of the TextBox inside the user control ... how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a Public Property in `AccountSearchControl.ascx`

```
public string TextBoxText {
    get {
        return TextBox1.Text;
    }
    set {
        TextBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

By default all of the Controls you place on the page have a `protected` visibility (Take a look at `AccountSearchControl.ascx.designed.cs` to see). So you need to expose a method for your page to access the Textbox.

Answer (score 3):

you want something like this on your usercontrol

```
public string textBoxValue
{ 
    get { return this.myTextBoxId.Text; }
    set { this.myTextBoxId.Text = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to access a textbox control inside an user control :

```
TextBox yourTextBox = (TextBox)AccountSearchControlBox.FindControl("your_textbox_ID");
```

Comment: this one is not problem, but sometimes you need to access a control at parent.. that case is really annoying :)